# fread : Specifying colClasses of file with 2 columns with same name, using col and col.1 does not work

Tags: r, fread, readr

`fread` : Specifying colClasses of file with 2 columns with same name, using col and col.1 does not work

```
fread(file, colClasses(col = "character", col.1 = "character"), check.names = TRUE)
```

It seems the `check.names = TRUE` is performed later, after the file is read. Is there any workaround to help do it. I need to preserve the precision of the columns col...

Comment: You can specify by column number as an alternative if that works for you - `fread("col col\n1 2", colClasses=list(character=1:2), check.names=TRUE)` ?

Comment: Yeah that's an option.. But my code is currently structured to take column names for some reason...

Comment: Somehow `readr::read_csv` works correctly here !