# fread importing empty as NA

Tags: r

I'm trying to import a csv with blanks read as `""`. Unfortunately they're all reading as `"NA"` now.

To better demonstrate the problem I'm also showing how `NA`, `"NA"`, and `""` are all mapping to the same thing (except in the very bottom example), which would prevent the easy workaround `dt[is.na(dt)] <- ""`

```
> write.csv(matrix(c("0","",NA,"NA"),ncol = 2),"MRE.csv")
```

Opening this in notepad, it looks like this

```
"","V1","V2"
"1","0",NA
"2","","NA"
```

So reading that back...

```
> fread("MRE.csv")
   V1 V1 V2
1:  1  0 NA
2:  2 NA NA
```

The documentation seems to suggest this but it does not work as described

```
> fread("MRE.csv",na.strings = NULL)
   V1 V1 V2
1:  1  0 NA
2:  2 NA NA
```

Also tried this which reads the `NA` as an actual NA, but the problem remains for the empty string which is read as `"NA"`

```
> fread("MRE.csv",colClasses=c(V1="character",V2="character"))
   V1 V1   V2
1:  1  0 <NA>
2:  2 NA   NA

> fread("MRE.csv",colClasses=c(V1="character",V2="character"))[,V2]
[1] NA   "NA"
```

data.table version 1.11.4

R version 3.5.1

Comment: If the rest of a column is numeric or integer, you *cannot* have blank strings in them (without coercing the column to `character`). If you add `colClasses=c(V1="character",V2="character")` in your call to `fread`, does it work?

Comment: It does not. Edited to show this.
Also I didn't have that; I wrote the `0` as `"0"`

Comment: Part of the problem in your example is that your `write.csv` is adding an explicit `NA` (unquoted string). The first row of data in `MRE.csv` is `"1","0",NA`, and the second row of data is `"2","","NA"`. Perhaps your example should use `write.csv(..., na="")`?

Comment: It doesn't matter that you wrote a string `"0"` in your `matrix` and `write.csv`, it is how it is interpreted by the reading function that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few possible things going on here:

1. Regardless of you writing `"0"` here, the reading function (`fread`) is inferring based on looking at a portion of the file. This is not uncommon (`readr` does it, too), and is controllable (with `colClasses=`).
2. This might be unique to your question here (and not your real data), but your call to `write.csv` is implicitly putting the literal `NA` letters in the file (not to be confused with `"NA"` where you have the literal string). This might be confusing things, even when you override with `colClasses=`.
3. You might already know this, but since `fread` is inferring that those columns are really `integer` classes, then they cannot contain empty strings: once determined to be a number column, anything non-number-like will be `NA`.

Let's redo your first csv-generating side to make sure we don't confound the situation.

```r
write.csv(matrix(c("0","",NA,"NA"),ncol = 2), "MRE.csv", na="")
```

(Below, I'm using `magrittr`'s pipe operator `%>%` merely for presentation, it is not required.)

The first example demonstrates `fread`'s inference. The second shows our overriding that behavior, and now we have blank strings in each `NA` spot that is not the *literal string* `"NA"`.

```r
fread("MRE.csv") %>% str
# Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ V1: int  1 2
#  $ V1: int  0 NA
#  $ V2: logi  NA NA
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

fread("MRE.csv", colClasses="character") %>% str
# Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ V1: chr  "1" "2"
#  $ V1: chr  "0" ""
#  $ V2: chr  "" "NA"
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

This can also be controlled on a per-column basis. One issue with this example is that `fread` is for some reason forcing the column of row-names to be named `V1`, the same as the next column. This looks like a bug to me, perhaps you can look at [Rdatatable's issues](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+V1) and potentially post a new one. (I might be wrong, perhaps this is intentional/known behavior.)

Because of this, per-column overriding seems to stop at the first occurrence of a column name.

```r
fread("MRE.csv", colClasses=c(V1="character", V2="character")) %>% str
# Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ V1: chr  "1" "2"
#  $ V1: int  0 NA
#  $ V2: chr  "" "NA"
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

One way around this is to go with an unnamed vector, requiring the same number of classes as the number of columns:

```r
fread("MRE.csv", colClasses=c("character","character","character")) %>% str
# Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ V1: chr  "1" "2"
#  $ V1: chr  "0" ""
#  $ V2: chr  "" "NA"
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Another way (thanks @thelatemail) is with a list:

```r
fread("MRE.csv", colClasses=list(character=2:3)) %>% str
# Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':    2 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ V1: int  1 2
#  $ V1: chr  "0" ""
#  $ V2: chr  "" "NA"
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Side note: if you need to preserve them as ints/nums, then:

1. if your concern is about how it affects follow-on calculations, then you can:

   1. fix the source of the data so that nulls are not provided;
   2. filter out the incomplete observations (rows); or
   3. fix the calculations to deal intelligently with missing data.
2. if your concern is about how it looks in a report, then whatever tool you are using to render in your report should have a mechanism for how to display `NA` values; for example, setting `options(knitr.kable.NA="")` before `knitr::kable(...)` will present them as empty strings.
3. if your concern is about how it looks on your *console*, you have two options:

   1. interfere with the data by iterating over each (intended) column and changing `NA` values to `""`; this only works on `character` columns, and is irreversible; or
   2. write your own subclass of `data.frame` that changes how it is displayed on the console; the benefit to this is that it is non-destructive; the problem is that you have to re-class each object where you want this behavior, and most (if not all) functions that output frames will likely inadvertently strip or omit that class from your input. (You'll need to write an S3 method of `print` for your subclass to do this.)

Comment: You can also specify `colClasses` by position in a list - see my comment from yesterday https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58178779/fread-specifying-colclasses-of-file-with-2-columns-with-same-name-using-col-a#comment102737825_58178779

Comment: Thanks, added to the answer.

Comment: thanks, glad to do it without hacky workarounds now

Comment: any idea whats with the `na.strings=NULL` not working though? is that a bug in data.table?

Comment: Looking at it, **yes**, I think it's a bug. If you look at `str(fread("MRE.csv",na.strings = NULL))`, you'll see that it is interpreting the third column as `logical` for which `""` is not meaningful, ergo `NA`. But since you told it to *not* try to infer null values, then it should guess that the second row is `character` and therefore the first row should be the empty string. That's a great example for a reproducible-issue; possibly related is https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3439, though only b/c it highlights the behavior of `na.strings=`.