# fwrite and fread empty strings

Tags: r, data.table, fwrite, fread

How can I make `fread` read `""` as an empty string (i.e. without manually specifying `colClasses`)? What justifies this `fread/fwrite` incompatibility and how to avoid it (i.e. is there a way to `fwrite` so that `fread` can read empty strings)?

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = 1, b = '')
fwrite(dt, file = 'out.csv')
dt2 <- fread('out.csv')

dt
#    a b
# 1: 1  
dt2
#    a  b
# 1: 1 NA
```

There are couple of closely related posts (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210406/fread-importing-empty-as-na), but it also asks for a trouble by specifying a numeric string). I think my case is much simpler yet more surprising/insidious given somewhat justified expectation that `fwrite` and `fread` should be able to handle the same data consistently.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [fread importing empty as NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210406/fread-importing-empty-as-na)

Comment: This is happening in this example because you have only 1 row of data, so the class of `b` is ambiguous (in a sense); while it may seem apparent to the reader that `""` as the CSV contents for that column suggests "string", it is not uncommon for all data types/classes to be quoted, so `""` is still ambiguous. With that, two resolutions for this: if there are rows in which `b` is clearly a non-empty string, this problem goes away; or if still 1 row, add `colClasses=c(b="character")` and this problem goes away.

Comment: @r2evans, I think you nailed it, if you turn your comment into an answer, I'd accept it

Comment: @r2evans, perhaps you also include a resolution that `na.strings = NULL` in `fread` should work, but does not at the moment due to [a bug](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3439) in `fread` (I found it thanks to @harre)

Comment: ValloVarik: the fact that that bug has been around for 3 years and has slipped version-milestones a few times (including _not the next release_) is perhaps frustrating; I love its stability, but that stability comes at the cost of slow and deliberate changes/updates/releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a combination of both a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210406/fread-importing-empty-as-na) and a current bug in [data.table#3439](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3439) where the empty strings are not recognized correctly.

Two ways to resolve *this* issue, and perhaps they will not be necessary when #3439 is fixed:

1. ensure that other rows in the `b` column are non-empty strings; you may not have control over this, so ...

   ```r
   writeLines(c("a,b", '1,""', '2,"b"'), "out.csv")
   fread("out.csv")
   #        a      b
   #    <int> <char>
   # 1:     1       
   # 2:     2      b
   ```
2. ensure that the `b` column is class `character`:

   ```r
   ### with the original 1-row CSV file
   fread("out.csv", colClasses=c(b="character"))
   #        a      b
   #    <int> <char>
   # 1:     1
   ```
3. When #3439 is resolved, you *should* be able to just do

   ```r
   fread("out.csv", na.string=NULL)
   ```